# Bit Math for QuestDB

Tags: questdb

Does the database QuestDB support BitMath, i.e. the ability to manipulate individual bits? I tried using field & 1 == true but I get the following in return:
unexpected character.

Answer (score 0):

QuestDB supports bitwise operators to assist with performing bitwise operations "bitmath". Consider browsing the QuestDB documentation found here: [QuestDBDocs](https://questdb.io/docs/reference/operators/bitwise)

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. Maybe it could help others to provide an example?

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31137943)